# Problem with focusing on WebBrowser control when pressing TAB key

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus, webbrowser-control

I'm making a Windows Forms application with VB.Net, Visual Studio 2015.
The `Form` has a `WebBrowser` control and other controls.

Whenever pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key on keyboard, it always focuses on a html element loaded in the `WebBrowser` control first. Then pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key again, the focus is switched between the HTML elements in the `WebBrowser` control.

Till ending up switching in all HTML elements, the focus doesn't switch to other controls in the `Form`.
Though I set `.TabIndex = 1000` and `.TabStop = false` in the `WebBrowser` control, it always focuses on a html element loaded in the `WebBrowser` control first, always first.

So, I want to disable focusing on the `WebBrowser` control by pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key or to disable the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key function in the `Form` entirely.

Comment: exactly, It always focus on a html elements in web browser control first. when pressing tap key.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  If you do not want the browser control to be a tabstop then set its TabStop property to false.

Comment: I tried to make sense of your question and improve its formatting. If any of you thinks that I made a mistake, please feel free to correct my edit.

Comment: though I already set 'tapstop = false' in web browser control, It always focuses on a html element loaded in web browser control first.

Answer (score 0):

I have to get the answer done in VB.NET soon, but for now here's the C# version of it:

First, an extended web browser control, that you'll have to use on the form, with a custom event when the tab key is pressed.

Here we call the TabStop = false to ensure this key gets processed.  Similar reasoning on WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled.

Then, we capture on the HTML Body, the key press event.

If the key code is a 9 (tab), we fire our event.

```
public class WebBrowserExtended : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{

    protected virtual void OnTabKeyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = TabKeyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler TabKeyEvent;

    public WebBrowserExtended() : base()
    {
        this.TabStop = false;
        this.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDocumentCompleted(WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDocumentCompleted(e);
        if (this.Document.Body != null)
            this.Document.Body.KeyDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_KeyDown);
    }

    private void Body_KeyDown(Object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyPressedCode == 9 && !e.CtrlKeyPressed)
        {
            this.OnTabKeyEvent(e);
            e.BubbleEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's is your event handler:

```
  private void webBrowser1_TabKeyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var controls = new List<Control>(this.Controls.Cast<Control>());
        var nextControl = controls.Where(c => c.TabIndex > webBrowser1.TabIndex).OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex).FirstOrDefault();
        if (nextControl != null)
            nextControl.Focus();
        else
            controls.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
    }
```

And here's the VB version of the control:

```
Public Class WebBrowserExtended
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTabKeyEvent(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent TabKeyEvent(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Event TabKeyEvent As EventHandler

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.TabStop = False
        Me.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDocumentCompleted(ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDocumentCompleted(e)
        If Me.Document.Body IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler Me.Document.Body.KeyDown, AddressOf Body_KeyDown
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Body_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
        If e.KeyPressedCode = 9 AndAlso Not e.CtrlKeyPressed Then
            Me.OnTabKeyEvent(e)
            e.BubbleEvent = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the VB event handler:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_TabKeyEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.TabKeyEvent

        Dim controls = New List(Of Control)(Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control))
        Dim nextControl = controls.Where(Function(c)
                                             Return c.TabIndex > WebBrowser1.TabIndex
                                         End Function).OrderBy(Function(c)
                                                                   Return c.TabIndex
                                                               End Function).FirstOrDefault()
        If Not controls Is Nothing Then
            nextControl.Focus()
        Else
            controls.OrderBy(Function(c)
                                 Return c.TabIndex
                             End Function).FirstOrDefault().Focus()
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. at first, your code level is very high, so I can't understand your code enough. by the way, I paste your code in my code. then an error occured. in webbrowser1_tabkeyevent handler, error message is that there is no 'tabkeyevent' event. nervously, I can't revise your code.

Comment: Private Sub WebBrowser1_TabKeyEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.TabKeyEvent <- there is an error. message is that " ther is no 'tabkeyevent' event". but i can;t revise or adapt your code

Comment: Is there a easy way to disable work of tab key(usually switching focus among controls) in win-form application perfectly?

Comment: @bbond you have to use the inherited web browser control ive created...its in the answer...the base control doesnt have a tab key event